# Amazon S3 - Cloudfront & Heroku CSS not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

i have successfully made asset pipeline setup on Heroku with Amazon S3. All link are OK, files are uploaded on S3, Bucket is shared like distribution, you can click and open file... 
I checked content type on amazon and it is text/css ....

But CSS want render o_O ...

Here is the link: http://stormy-mist-3168.herokuapp.com/excursions

Thanks!

Comment: does it work locally? There seems to be something funny with your html - I don't see any opening body tag until line 297 and even then it is closed one line later after the gmap div.

Comment: I'll check that, thanks for pointing out. It works localy but only when assets are local.

Comment: Well i fixed "body" thing, it works localy when assets are local, but for 2 days i can't get damn app to pull those images and css from amazon ... Files are there... I just can't see why... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a stylesheeting problem - for starters try removing your colorbox stylesheet and recompile and push to Heroku, from my quick testing I found a problem in there somewhere.

Comment: You save my 2 days of frustrations, I'm going now to celebrate new year. Thank you sir Beynon !

Comment: If you have time to wrote few words about how did you manage to find this error, just for community. Thanks !

Comment: Trial and error. I saved your html and css locally - then took out chunks of the css file until I got it to render correctly, then put bits back in at a time - I think it was only a single line of the colorbox css that was messing it up infact.